# R：par(cex.lab=2) doesn't work in plot(effect(),…)

Tags: r, plot, error-handling

I made a linear regression with a database including *group(1=smoke,2=control)* , *gender(1=m,2=f)* and a dependent variable like *weight*.  I want to see the interactions between group and gender with a plot. I need to **change the size** of the label of axes but it doesn't work with `par()`. The code is like this:

```
lin <- lm(weight ~ group + gender + group:gender, data=data)
par(cex.lab = 2, cex.axis = 2)
library(effects)
plot(effect("group:gender",lin,,list(gender=c(1,2))),multiline=T)
```

The size doesn't change. And if I want to delete the axis like this:

```
plot(effect("group:gender",lin,,list(gender=c(1,2))),multiline=T,axes=FALSE)
```

It gives me this error:

```
$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why that is happening, my guess is that the class(effect) is "eff" which perhaps may not be suited for plot to render it properly, to avoid this convert this object to data.frame and then use the `par` functionality to do your task.

**Answer to your question:** Here if you change par options with different values, your font size will change like in the graph which I have mentioned down.

You can do this:

```
library(effects)

lin <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + am + am:cyl, data=mtcars)
par(cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1.2, cex.main=1.2, cex.sub=1.2) #Here you can check, the par options, if you change it the font will incrase or decrese
effect1 <- data.frame(effect("cyl:am",lin,,list(cyl=c(4,6,8))))
effects <- effect1[,c("cyl","am", "fit")] ##Keeping only the required columns
```

You can do a plotting with effects , by using all three objects: cyl, am and fit, However, the lines are getting joined , I am not aware any functionality like ggplot's group in base plot R. So I will split it and then plot it.

```
xvals <- split(effects$am,effects$cyl) #split x-axis basis cyl
yvals <- split(effects$fit,effects$cyl) #split y-axis basis cyl

plot(1:max(unlist(xvals)),xlim = c(0,max(unlist(xvals))),ylim=(c(0,max(unlist(yvals)))),type="n", main="plot b/w mpg, am * cyl",  
     xlab="am", ylab="mpg") #adding header, labels and xlim and ylim to the graphs

Map(lines,xvals,yvals,col=c("red","blue","black"),pch=1:2,type="o") #plotting the objects using Map
legend("bottomright", legend=c("8", "6", "4"),
       col=c("red", "blue", "black"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8) #adding the legend
```

**Output**:

**With par options fixed at 1.2**
[image]

**With par options fixed at 1.5:**

[image]